# How many words can be formed from the letters of the word CINEMA such that it neither starts with C nor ends with A?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many words can be formed from the letters of the word CINEMA such that it neither starts with C nor ends with A?

My approach: CINEMA

First character not C and last not A then first and last place can be filled in 5-5 ways, so there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 5 = 600$ permutations.

[My approach of solving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynNO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, please include the question in the body of the question, not just the title.  Also, please type your answer rather than providing a link to it since links can get broken, it may not be possible to search a picture for your work, and users who rely on screen readers may not be able to read your work.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since CINEMA has six distinct letters, there are $6!$ permutations of its letters.  From these, we must subtract those permutations with a C in the first position or an A in the last position.

There are $5!$ permutations of the letters of the word CINEMA in which there is a C in the first position since the other five letters can be permuted in the last five positions.  By symmetry, there are $5!$ permutations with an A in the last position.

However, if we subtract $2 \cdot 5!$ from $6!$, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted each permutation with a C in the first position and an A in the last position twice, once when we subtracted those permutations with a C in the first position and once when we subtracted those permutations with an A in the last position.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.  There are $4!$ permutations of the letters of the word CINEMA that contain a C in the first position and an A in the last position since the remaining four letters can be permuted in the remaining four positions.

Hence, the number of permutations of the word CINEMA that neither start with C nor end with A is
$$6! - 2 \cdot 5! + 4!$$
by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

*What is wrong with your solution?*

If you fill the first position with a letter other than C, the number of choices for the last position depends on whether you filled the first position with an A or not.

To do a direct count, consider the following cases:

1. The A is placed in the first position and the C is placed in the last position.
2. The A is placed in the first position and the C is not placed in the last position.
3. The C is placed in the last position and the A is not placed in the first position.
4. The A is not placed in the first position and the C is not placed in the last position.

If A is placed in the first position and C is placed in the last position, there are $4!$ ways to permute the remaining letters.

If the A is placed in the first position and C is not placed in the last position, there are $4$ ways to place the C and $4!$ ways to place the remaining letters.  Thus, there are $4 \cdot 4!$ such permutations.

By symmetry, there are also $4 \cdot 4!$ permutations in which the C is placed in the last position and the A is not placed in the first position.

If A is not placed in the first position and C is not placed in the last position, there are $4$ ways to place the A, $3$ ways to place the C, and $4!$ ways to arrange the remaining letters, so there are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 4!$ such permutations.

Since the four cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of admissible permutations is
$$4! + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4! + 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 4!$$
which agrees with the answer obtained above.